# How to fix error in VBA code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to email the sheet within workbook, sometimes the code works but sometimes returns an errors.

This line kicks error is,:

```
If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
```

Error says:
**Run-time error '52'**

Bad file name or number

Below's the code I'm using:

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
MsgBox "Success!"
End Sub
```

Comment: The error specifies that your're referencing an invalid file path. Have a look at the cells that contains the file paths you might need to account for special characters.

Comment: I'm sure that you have assigned proper File Path,,         `Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")` in those cells,, cozz the error specifies that the code unable to find the File in the Path. You may try once ,, `"C:\Users\Folder\Filename"` If file path is okay then use this line as,,`If Dir(FileCell) <> "" Then` ☺